# Counting sublists containing 0

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

Given a list: `data = {{0, 2}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}}`. I would like to count the number of sublists which contain zero.

```
Count[data, {0, _}] + Count[data, {_, 0}] - Count[data, {0, 0}]
```

Is there any better/efficient way to do this?

Comment: `Cases[data, {0, _} | {_, 0}] // Length`

Comment: Or `Count[data, a : {__, __} /; MemberQ[a, 0]]`

Comment: Or `Count[data, {___, 0, ___}]`

Comment: Thanks. I think they should add these in the `Count` documentation.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/count-sublists-which-match-pattern

Comment: @MichaelE2 Pity that question never gained momentum, but a perfect example on why someone should ask a single, clear-cut question instead of four.

Comment: @Kuba He's subtracting it once because `{0, 0}` is matched twice...

Comment: @rm-rf right, I should have focus longer :p

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the behavior  of `Times` in case of multiplication by (exact) zero:

```
Count[Times @@@ data, 0]
```

> 3

As proposed by MichaelE2, this can be considerably faster depending on the structure and size of the input:

```
Count[Times @@ Transpose[data], 0]
```

> 3

Comment: Somewhat faster, and much faster on packed arrays: `Count[Times @@ Transpose[data], 0]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 wicked!

Comment: @MichaelE2 added your version in to preserve it for posterity (and performance) - if you want to post separately, lemme know :-)

Comment: It's fine as part of yours.  It's basically the same idea, and the two belong together.

Comment: @MichaelE2 totally. Uh, and it seems your solution wins the speed contest for long list of tuples hands down.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a reasonably fast one:

```
countZ = 
  Length[Union @@ Map[SparseArray[#]["NonzeroPositions"] &, Transpose[1 - Unitize[#]]]] &
```

you use it as

```
countZ[data]
```

If you don't want to use SparseArrays, this will give roughly similar performance:

```
countZAlt = Total @ Unitize[Last@Dimensions@# - Total[Unitize[#], {2}]] &
```

Comment: Great, this is a oneliner tutorial :-)

Comment: @YvesKlett All right, point taken - I added another version which does not use `SparseArray` :)

Answer (score 8):

For long sublists it might be reasonable to immediately terminate element-checking after first 0 is encountered: logical operators and `Position` exhibit such shortcutting.

```
data = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {100, 100000}];

AbsoluteTiming@Count[Times @@ Transpose[data], 0]
AbsoluteTiming@Count[Min /@ Abs@data, 0 | 0.]
AbsoluteTiming@countMinC[data]    
AbsoluteTiming@Count[Times @@@ data, 0]
AbsoluteTiming@Fold[Boole@Not@FreeQ[#2, 0] + # &, 0, data] 
AbsoluteTiming@countZ@data 
AbsoluteTiming@countZAlt@data 
AbsoluteTiming@Count[Position[#, 0, 1, 1] & /@ data, Except@{}]
AbsoluteTiming@Count[Simplify[And @@@ data], False]
AbsoluteTiming@Total[Map[Total, data /. {0 -> 1, _Integer -> 0}] /. {0 -> 0, _Integer -> 1}]
```

> ```
> {1.244071, 100} (* MichaelE2 *)
> {0.048003, 100} (* s0rce *)
> {0.043002, 100} (* s0rce compiled *)
> {0.924053, 100} (* Yves *)
> {0.067004, 100} (* rm -rf *)
> {0.844048, 100} (* Leonid countZ *)
> {0.049003, 100} (* Leonid countZalt *)
> {0.207012, 100} (* Position *)
> {2.551146, 100} (* And *)
> {2.282131, 100} (* Ymareth *)
> ```

`Simplify` of course could be problematic if data is longer or elements are more complex than integers... Let's check it on many more shorter sublists:

```
data = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {100000, 10}];
(* ... *)
```

> ```
> {0.018001,65083} (* MichaelE2 *)
> {0.022001,65083} (* s0rce *)
> {0.004000,65083} (* s0rce compiled *)
> {0.125007,65083} (* Yves *)
> {0.040002,65083} (* rm -rf *)
> {0.025001,65083} (* Leonid countZ *)
> {0.007000,65083} (* Leonid countZalt *)
> {0.286016,65083} (* Position *)
> {30.547747,65083 (* And *)
> {0.323018,65083} (* Ymareth *)
> ```

Of course, compiling `Times` (I guess the only one that is directly compilable) wins over all the others:

```
countC = Compile[{{d, _Integer, 2}}, Count[Times @@@ d, 0],
   Parallelization -> True , CompilationTarget -> "C",  RuntimeAttributes -> Listable,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Comment: There is also the second solution in my post, `countZAlt`, which performs much better than my first one on your first test. Mind including it in your benchmarks?

Comment: Oh wow... I didn't mine was _that_ fast! BTW, 0. for Leonid's doesn't seem right... I don't get that (it seems slower than mine). However, his `countZAlt` is faster.

Comment: @Leonid Sure, sorry for the delay, I had to test some of my own solutions as well :)

Comment: Would you mind including @MichaelE2´s version `Count[Times @@ Transpose[data], 0]` in the timings?

Comment: @Yves s0rce kindly did that, it definitely deserved the inclusion! Next time please feel free to edit in!

Comment: @IstvánZachar would have inserted, but timings only make sense on the same machine...

Comment: I am puzzled by your rationale and counts for your second and third data structures.

Comment: @David My intention was to produce a long list with short sublists and a short list with long sublists. In the latter case it could make a huge difference if one can do shortcutting, but not in the first case.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a fast straight forward procedural implementation compiled to C, this requires all the sublists to have the same length but performs similar when interested in sublists containing an arbitrary integer, not just 0.

```
simpleC = 
  Compile[{{list, _Integer, 2}}, 
   Block[{count = 0}, 
    Do[If[MemberQ[sublist, 0], count++], {sublist, list}]; count], 
   Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

and a faster parallel implementation

```
simpleCparallel = 
  Compile[{{sublist, _Integer, 1}}, Boole[MemberQ[sublist, 0]], 
   Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

data = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {100, 100000}];
simpleC[data] // AbsoluteTiming
Total@simpleCparallel[data] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.018001,100} 
> {0.010001,100}
> ```

```
data = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {10000000, 10}];
simpleC[data] // AbsoluteTiming
Total@simpleCparallel[data] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.554032,6513970}
> {0.346020,6513970}
> ```

This simple solution seems to be reasonably quick:

```
Count[Min /@ Abs[data],  0| 0.]
```

and a slightly faster compiled version

```
countMinC = 
  Compile[{{d, _Integer, 2}}, Count[Min /@ Abs[d], 0], 
   Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

and another option that is slightly faster for short sublists with inspiration from @Leonid

```
countMinC2 = 
  Compile[{{d, _Integer, 2}}, 
   Length@d - Total[Unitize[Min /@ Abs[d]]], Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Comment: `Count` is based on patterns, so the fully robust version will probably `Count[Min /@ Abs[data], 0| 0.]`. This probably won't affect the compiled version though.

Comment: `Abs[]` (see edit) should fix that.

Comment: @Leonid Be fair, almost everyone (even OP) omitted real 0. or `PossibleZeroQ` :)

Comment: @IstvánZachar Well, fair enough. I did not, however :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin fixed now. Thanks. Compiled version doesn't matter as it needs to be specific to be either `Intergers` or `Reals`. @IstvánZachar, timings added to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution:

```
Fold[Boole@Not@FreeQ[#2, 0] + # &, 0, list]
(* 3 *)
```

Comment: There shall be a Microtutorial badge! BTW I like this frog better than the last one.

Comment: @YvesKlett Me too!

Answer (score 5):

Here's my late entry using `Select`

```
Select[data, MemberQ[#, 0] &] // Length
```

OR

```
Select[data, Count[#, 0] != 0 &] // Length
```

With compiled version:

```
countzero = Compile[{{data, _Integer, 2}}, 
  Select[data, MemberQ[#, 0] &] // Length, Parallelization -> True,
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's another set of timings based on the data structure of the problem as originally proposed.  The count of lists with at least one zero appears right after the timing.

```
 r := RandomInteger[{0, 9}]
 data = Table[{r, r}, {i, 10^6}];
"Long list with short sublists"

{Count[Times @@ Transpose[data], 0] // AbsoluteTiming, "MichaelE2"}
{Fold[Boole@Not@FreeQ[#2, 0] + # &, 0, data] // 
  AbsoluteTiming, "rm-rf"}
{countzero[data] // AbsoluteTiming, "RunnyKine -compiled"}
{countC[data] // AbsoluteTiming, "István -compiled"}
{Count[data, {0, _} | {_, 0}] // 
  AbsoluteTiming, "Blackbird, using Count"}
{Length@Cases[data, {0, _} | {_, 0}] // AbsoluteTiming, "Blackbird"}   
{LengthWhile[Map[Sort, data], #[[1]] == 0 &] // 
  AbsoluteTiming, "lalmei"}    
{Count[Times @@@ data, 0] // AbsoluteTiming, "Yves Klett"}
{Count[data, {___, 0, ___}] // AbsoluteTiming, "jVincent"}
{Count[Sort /@ data, {0, _}] // AbsoluteTiming, "David Carraher"}
{countZ@data // AbsoluteTiming, "Leonid #1"}    
{Select[data, MemberQ[#, 0] &] // Length // 
  AbsoluteTiming, "RunnyKine"}
{Select[data, Count[#, 0] != 0 &] // Length // 
  AbsoluteTiming, "RunnyKine"}
{Total[Map[Total, 
     data /. {0 -> 1, _Integer -> 0}] /. {0 -> 0, _Integer -> 1}] // 
  AbsoluteTiming, "Ymareth"}
{Count[Simplify[And @@@ data], False] // AbsoluteTiming, "István?"}
{Count[Position[#, 0, 1, 1] & /@ data, Except@{}] // 
  AbsoluteTiming, "István?"}
{Count[data, a : {__, __} /; MemberQ[a, 0]] // 
  AbsoluteTiming, "Anon"}
{countZAlt@data // AbsoluteTiming, "Leonid #2"}
```

[image: timings]

---

**Testing lists with sublists of varying lengths.**

There were some anomalies when we tested sublists of varying lengths. Note that there are 2*10^6 random integers in each of the cases tested.

```
   Table[data[k] = RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {10^(6 - k), 2*10^k}], {k, 0, 
   6}];
"Long list with short sublists"
result = {
  {"SublistLength", 2, 20, 2*10^2, 2*10^3, 2*10^4, 2*10^5, 2*10^6},
  Prepend[
   Table[Count[Times @@ Transpose[data[j]], 0] // AbsoluteTiming, {j, 
     0, 6}], "MichaelE2"],
  Prepend[
   Table[Fold[Boole@Not@FreeQ[#2, 0] + # &, 0, data[j]] // 
     AbsoluteTiming, {j, 0, 6}], "rm-rf"],
  Prepend[Table[countzero[data[j]] // AbsoluteTiming, {j, 0, 6}], 
   "RunnyKine-compiled"],
  Prepend[Table[countC[data[j]] // AbsoluteTiming, {j, 0, 6}], 
   "István-compiled"],
  Prepend[
   Table[Count[Times @@@ data[j], 0] // AbsoluteTiming, {j, 0, 6}], 
   "Yves Klett"],
  Prepend[
   Table[Count[data[j], {___, 0, ___}] // AbsoluteTiming, {j, 0, 6}], 
   "jVincent"],
  Prepend[Table[countZ@data[j] // AbsoluteTiming, {j, 0, 6}], 
   "Leonid #1"],
  Prepend[Table[countZAlt@data[j] // AbsoluteTiming, {j, 0, 6}], 
   "Leonid #2"],
  Prepend[
   Table[Count[Simplify[And @@@ data[j]], False] // 
     AbsoluteTiming, {j, 0, 6}], "István"],
  Prepend[
   Table[Count[Position[#, 0, 1, 1] & /@ data[j], Except@{}] // 
     AbsoluteTiming, {j, 0, 6}], "István"],
  Prepend[
   Table[Total[
      Map[Total, 
        data[j] /. {0 -> 1, _Integer -> 0}] /. {0 -> 0, _Integer -> 
         1}] // AbsoluteTiming, {j, 0, 6}], "Ymareth"]}
Grid[result, Dividers -> {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}]
```

[image: timings 2]

Comment: Did you by chance omit a definition for `r`?

Comment: Could you kindly include my method `countzero`, I'm curious to see how well `Select` performs here.

Comment: Yves. Yes, I did. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: RunnyKine, I don't know how to run the compiled version. Simply running your code is clearly not enough.

Comment: Just do `countzero[data]` after evaluating `countzero`

Comment: I get an order of magnitude increase in speed on my machine compared to the non-compiled version. Thanks for adding mine to the list.

Comment: RunnyKine.  Yes, so did I.  But note that there are noncompiled functions that are as fast as your compiled function.

Comment: @David Thanks David, I think I found the mistake on mine! I needed ANOTHER sort, it should slow down by factor or two I believe.

Comment: So, David, did you deliberately make your input data unpacked? This drastically affects the timings.

Comment: Leonid, I packed it, after your suggestion, using `ToPackedArray`, but found negligible differences.  Here's the code: `Needs["Developer`"]; Table[data[k] = 
   ToPackedArray@RandomInteger[{0, 9}, {10^(6 - k), 2*10^k}], {k, 0, 
   6}];`

Comment: If the question marks after my name are indicating uncertainty about source then yes, they are mine. If they indicate questionable usefulness and sanity - well, I can live with them :)

Comment: The question marks were to indicate that I was unsure about the authorship.

Answer (score 3):

By substitution...

```
Total[Map[Total, data /. {0 -> 1, _Integer -> 0}] /. {0 -> 0, _Integer -> 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the sublists are always of length 2 then this is fast:

```
Length[data] - Dot @@ Transpose[Unitize @ data]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{0, 2}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}};
```

Using `OrderlessPatternSequence`

```
Count[data, {OrderlessPatternSequence[0, _]}]
```

3

The above would only count pairs (single `Blank`). If we want to
count sublists of arbitrary lengths, we use `BlankSequence`

```
data = {{0, 2}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 0}};

Count[data, {OrderlessPatternSequence[0, __]}]
```

4

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{0, 2}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}};
```

Using `SequenceCases`:

```
Length@SequenceCases[data, {s : {__} /; ! FreeQ[s, 0]} :> s]

(*3*)
```

Or using `Cases`:

```
Length@Cases[data, s_ /; ! FreeQ[s, 0] :> s]

(*3*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{0, 2}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}};

Count[True]@Map[ContainsAny[{0}]][data]

Count[Unitize[data], Alternatives @@ {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}

FirstPosition[#, 0, Nothing] & /@ data // Length
```

and the unnecessary one:

```
(RegionMember[InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}], #] || 
     RegionMember[InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], #] ) & /@ data // 
 Count[True]
```

---

> 3

Answer (score -1):

Using a built in function called LengthWhile and Sort.

LengthWhile gives the length of all the continuous elements that meet a criteria.
So in order to use it we have to first sort the list and sublists first.

```
LengthWhile[Sort@Map[Sort, data], #[[1]] == 0 &]
```

> 3

Comment: Sorting is an overkill for the problem and it most probably is disastrous for long sublists.

Comment: @IstvanZachar I thought so too, but it is actually not that bad. It is actually faster then the uncompiled Times@ and Leonid's Sparse Array one, in the case of your large data test.